# Reload Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Такая проблема, по нажатию кнопки поиска у меня возвращается список, под который на фрагменте создаются layout's. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при каждом нажатии кнопки фрагмент перезагружался, чтобы выдача каждый раз была с нуля. Беда в том, что при использовании `detach` и `attach` список не отображается вообще. То есть он появляется на какую-то долю секунды и тут же фрагмент "чистится", не могу даже отловить, в какой момент отображается список и исчезает, ибо происходит это не внутри метода (тут я видимо вообще чего-то не понимаю). Метод выглядит так:

```
public void searchRestaurantButtonClick(View view) {

    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(fragment);
    ft.attach(fragment);
    ft.commit();

    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    String searchText = searchEditText.getText().toString();

    List<Restaurant> restaurantsList = getRestaurantsList(searchText);

    LinearLayout verticalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newsFragment);
    for (Restaurant each : restaurantsList) {
        LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView titleTextView = new TextView(this);
        titleTextView.setText(each.getTitle());
        horizontalLayout.addView(titleTextView);

        verticalLayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }
}
```

Если блок с `FragmentTransaction` закомментировать, то список возвращается и нормально отображается, но, естественно, при повторном запросе там и остается, а результат нового запроса (следующий список) отображается под предыдущим списком. Может кто-то объяснить, в чем подвох? Пробовал также сделать через `replace`, но тогда при запросе возвращается ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment FragmentNews{2abadd29 #0 id=0x7f0a0050}: was 2131361872 now 2131361880
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мсье знает толк в извращениях, я вижу...
Уберите это

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(fragment);
    ft.attach(fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

А после этой строчки

```
LinearLayout verticalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newsFragment);
```

добавьте такое

```
verticalLayout.removeAllViews()
```

Это удалит все, что было в `verticalLayout` до этого

Comment: Мсье нифига не знает, поэтому получаются извращения :) Ваш вариант проблему решает, спасибо!